# how do i transfer in plaid account using prime trust?

Tags: plaid

I'm tring to ach transfer from prime trust with plaid. I'm able to generate access token and public token and processocer token from plaid  but when I try to call

> https://sandbox.primetrust.com/v2/funds-transfer-methods

i'm getting

> public does not have access to funds_transfer_methods

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTofe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your Plaid account enabled for the integration?  You don't mention doing that step, but Prime Trust needs to be set to on on the [integrations page](https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/integrations).